# sending an array from a single choice select using php

Tags: php

why the following code doesn't work? i want the user to select one of two choices: "apple" or "orange", after that the form should send the entire array to which the choice belong to $_GET(could've used $_POST but i wanted to see what happens in the query string).. 
the thing is nothing prints out! it just says "Array"... if i was using echo to print the array sent maybe i would've understand but it's should've displayed one of the two subarrays selected.
i'm just starting to learn php, so any detailed help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="GET">
    <?php 
        $fruits=array(
                        "a"=>array("name"=>"apple","price"=>130),
                        "b"=>array("name"=>"orange","price"=>100));
        //generating a single choice droplist:
        echo '<select name="tab[]">'; //tab[] because i want to send one of the two arrays a or b
        echo "<br>";
        foreach ($fruits as $key => $value)
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value['name'].'</option><br>';
        }
        echo "</select>";
    ?>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="OK!">
    <br>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
   print_r($_GET['tab']); //it prints the string "Array", not one of the two sub-arrays a and b
?>
```

Comment: You are sending only one value, but the sent value is not even an array, it is just a string.

Comment: thank you for responding, would you please care to explain what you mean by one value? i don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this statement in your `foreach` loop.

```
echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value['name'].'</option><br>';
```

`$value` is an array, not a value. And that's why it's breaking your HTML.

> ... i want the user to select one of two choices: "apple" or "orange", after that the form should send the entire array to which the choice belong to `$_GET`

- Change your `<select>` element from `echo '<select name="tab[]">';` to `echo '<select name="tab">';`
- Make use of [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to generate URL-encoded query string from your array and use that query string as the value in the `value` attribute. So change your `foreach` loop in the following way,

  ```
  foreach ($fruits as $key => $value){
      $output = '<option value="';
      $output .= http_build_query($value);
      $output .= '">'.$value['name'].'</option><br>';
      echo $output;
  }
  ```

  And after the form submission, you can use [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function to parse `$_GET['tab']` to get the original array back, like this:

  ```
  parse_str($_GET['tab'], $output);
  // echo $output['name'];
  // echo $output['price'];
  ```

---

**Sidenote:** If you want to see the complete superglobal structure, do `var_dump($_GET);`

Comment: thnx for responding, well i'm starting to understand where's the problem, and i've tried your code and it does work, however, the problem is with http_build_query() is that it formats everything to a query string. if only there's a way so i can pass one of the arrays a or b, to $_GET while preserving the array structure so i can retrieve the array intact instead of a string

Comment: @johnDas I've completely updated my answer. Please go through the answer once again.

Comment: just out of curiousity.. is there a more simple method to achieve the same result? thnx anyway

Comment: @RajdeepPaul great answer btw. Merry Xmas buddy ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, merry Christmas and happy holidays! ;-)

Comment: @RajdeepPaul *Merci!*

Comment: @johnDas I believe this is the best way to achieve your desired result, unless ofcourse you change the underlying business logic.

Comment: @johnDas *Merry Christmas buddy. ;-)*

Answer (score 0):

Change from `'<select name="tab[]">'` to `'<select name="tab">'`
Because you are choosing only one item. You have to set [] (array sing) when you'll choose multiple values like multiple checkboxes. In this case, this is a dropdown where you're going to select only one option. It does not matter whatever the value of the dropdown. It should be an array or a single item. So when you'll select only one value, you should not use array sign ([]) in the key.